# How to render nested array elements in React?

Tags: reactjs, rendering, array.prototype.map

I want to render nested array elements. To render elements I used .map but it is not working for second array.

> Using list=[{value: 'One', list:[{value: 'abc', selected: false},
>   {value: 'efg', selected: false}]}, {value: 'Two', list: [{value:
>   'psr', selected: false}]}];

```
   list.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <ul >{item.value}</ul>
            item.list.map((subitem, i) => {
              return (
                 <ul >{subitem.value}</ul>
              )
            })
          </div>
        )
      })
```

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to render them in nested lists, or flatten the array?

Comment: @TomFenech I have to show nested array details

Comment: I can see your array, what you need to show us is the desired structure of the HTML that you are trying to produce. At the moment, what you have is invalid.

Comment: @TomFenech yes. I don't know how to use .map for nested array

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2611/ Check this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this.    You missed **{ }** before your second `map`

```
 list.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <ul >{item.value}</ul>
               {
                item.list.map((subitem, i) => {
                  return (
                     <ul ><li>{subitem.value}</li></ul>
                  )
                })
               }
              </div>
            )
          }
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2611/

Comment: Try adding an explanation to your answer!

Comment: @TomFenech I was in middle of adding

Comment: Your answer deals with a possible syntax error but fails to take into account the fact that a text node is not a permitted child of a `<ul>` element.

Comment: Throws error. It says Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Referd item.list.map

Comment: Okat. Thanks @Ved

Comment: @AnushaNilapu Welcome .

Comment: @Ved Still getting same error. I can see item.list has array but it fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143265/discussion-between-anusha-nilapu-and-ved).

Comment: Last line should be }), in the jsfiddle it is correct