# Nested arrays iteration on React Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I have that nested array and can't figure out how to iterate it. Need to get all "ingredients" from each nested array inside the big one.
I render 20 recipes, individually need to also render the ingredients for each one respectively.
If it is not understandable I will clarify it, or at least try

[image]

Comment: What is the output UI that you want to have? And what have you tried?

Comment: Does nested array contains different recipes ? Then it depends on the way you want to render these details in your UI. Please explain it further.

Comment: Don't post images of code, take the time to type out your attempts, your input and expected output.

Comment: see: [How to render nested array elements in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756283/how-to-render-nested-array-elements-in-react)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since the array is only nested by one degree, a simple call to [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) should do the trick:

```js
recipies = [
  ['ingrediant 1a', 'ingrediant 2a'],
  ['ingrediant 1b', 'ingrediant 2b']
];

result = recipies.flat();

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Not precisely, that function's call just mashed all up. I need to get into the first array, and the, for each little array (some of them have 4 ingredients, some 3), need to map it again and return an LI with the value of that ingredient.

Comment: @SintaxisDev I'm not sure I understand this statement. Can you please edit your question and share the output you're expecting?