# I need help rendering a nested array in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, multidimensional-array, filter

I have an array of Departments ([Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PduMb.png)) that I was able to map but when I get to the nested array, I cant seem to render them into separate divs. I am building a filter from a JSON file. I have the Departments split into their own box, I now need the Subjects split into each their own div within the box of their respective Departments. I tried to map again but it tells me that it can't read the state...I've gotten mixed up and know it's something small I'm missing. Please help.

```html
import "./main.css";
import info from "./departments.json"
import { useState } from 'react';


function App({ name, subjects }) {

  const [state, setState] = useState(info);



  const handleBtns = (e) => {
  
    let word = e.target.value;

    if (word === 'All') {
      setState(info)
    }
    else if (word === 'Architecture and History of Art') {
      const filtered = info.filter(item => item.name === 'Architecture and History of Art');
      setState(filtered);
    }
    else if (word === 'Physical Education') {
      const filtered = info.filter(item => item.name === 'Physical Education');
      setState(filtered);
    }
    else if (word === 'Physics') {
      const filtered = info.filter(item => item.name === 'Physics');
      setState(filtered);
    }
    else if (word === 'Εlectrical & Electronics Engineering') {
      const filtered = info.filter(item => item.name === 'Εlectrical & Electronics Engineering');
      setState(filtered);
    }
    else if (word === 'Computer Science') {
      const filtered = info.filter(item => item.name === 'Computer Science');
      setState(filtered);
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="btns">
        <button value="All" onClick={handleBtns}>All</button>
        <button value="Architecture and History of Art" onClick={handleBtns}>Architecture and History of Art</button>
        <button value="Physical Education" onClick={handleBtns}>Physical Education</button>
        <button value="Physics" onClick={handleBtns}>Physics</button>
        <button value="Εlectrical & Electronics Engineering" onClick={handleBtns}>Εlectrical & Electronics Engineering</button>
        <button value="Computer Science" onClick={handleBtns}>Computer Science</button>
      </div>
      
      <div className="single-box">
        <div className="mob">
          {state.map((item) => (
            <div className="departments-wrapper" key={item.name}>
              <h4><b>{item.name}</b></h4>
              {state.map((item) => (
              <div className="subjects-wrapper" key={item.subjects}>
              <div className="subjects">{item.subjects}</div>
                </div>
                  ))}
          </div>
              ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
 )
}
          
      
export default App
```

```html
[{
        "name": "Architecture and History of Art",
        "subjects": [
            "Painting",
            "Sculpture",
            "Architecture",
            "Drawing, printing, photography, collage and film",
            "The art and architecture of antiquity",
            "Art, religion and society",
            "Art, society and politics"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Physical Education",
        "subjects": [
            "Anatomy and physiology",
            "Social, cultural and ethical influences",
            "Skill acquisition and psychology",
            "Health, fitness and training"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Physics",
        "subjects": [
            "Physical quantities and units",
            "Measurement techniques",
            "Dynamics",
            "Forces, density and pressure",
            "Work, energy and power",
            "Deformation of solids",
            "Waves",
            "Superposition",
            "Electric fields",
            "Current of electricity",
            "D.C. circuits",
            "Particle and nuclear physics"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Εlectrical & Electronics Engineering",
        "subjects": [
            "Circuit Theory & Networks",
            "Electrical & Electronic Measurement",
            "Data Structure & Algorithms",
            "Materials Science",
            "Mathematics",
            "Numerical Methods & Programming",
            "Computer Organization & Architecture",
            "Technical Report writing"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Computer Science",
        "subjects": [
            "Information representation",
            "Communication and Internet technologies",
            "Hardware",
            "Processor fundamentals",
            "System software",
            "Security, privacy and data integrity",
            "Ethics and ownership",
            "Database and data modelling",
            "Algorithm design and problem-solving",
            "Data representation",
            "Programming",
            "Software development",
            "Monitoring and control systems"
        ]
    }
]
```

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4jww.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdRfB.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render nested array elements in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756283/how-to-render-nested-array-elements-in-react)

Comment: Shouldn’t you map over item.subjects? {item.subjects.map((subject) => ())}

Comment: when I map over subjects, it puts all subjects into a div, but also puts all subjects from all departments into each department.   So, Physics now has ALL of the subjects from Art wrapped in one div along with All  subjects from Physics as well as 3 more divs with subjects from the other classes. Ive added a new picture

Comment: What is the new code you tried, you’re still missing something. Davis Owen seems to have a solution that could work, I can’t test anything at the moment, but I believe you’re incorrectly passing {item.subjects} in the second map instead of {subject} as he shows in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what youre looking for?

```
{state.map((item) => (
   <div className="departments-wrapper" key={item.name}>
       <h4><b>{item.name}</b></h4>
       <div className="subjects-wrapper">
          {item.subjects.map((subject) => (
             <div className="subjects">{subject}</div>
          ))}
       </div>
   </div>
))}
```