# map array inside an array Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I map array inside ?

```
array = [[{},{},{}],[{},{}],[{},],[{},{},{},{}]]
```

I tried

```
data.map((array) => {
            console.log(array);
            return (
                array.map((doc) => <p>{doc}</p>)
            );
        })
```

Comment: And what happened? What output are you _expecting_?

Comment: do you want to flat and map?

Comment: an "id" but it looks like I can't 2 map in JSX

Comment: actually you can

Comment: I just want to map data in array inside

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756283/how-to-render-nested-array-elements-in-react

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `flat` and then `map` like this

```js
const data =  [[{value: 1},{value: 2},{value: 3}],[{value: 4},{value: 5}],[{value: 6}],[{value: 7},{value: 8},{value: 9},{value: 10}]]


const html = data.flat().map(d => `<p>${d.value}</p>`).join('')

const htmlReduce = data.reduce((res, item) => [...res, ...item], []).map(d => `<p>${d.value}</p>`).join('')

console.log(html, htmlReduce)
```

based on your code

```
data.flat().map((doc, i) => <p key={i}>{doc}</p>)
```

for old browsers

```
data.reduce((res, item) => [...res, ...item], []).map((doc, i) => <p key={i}>{doc}</p>)
```

Comment: The flat method is not yet implemented in common browsers (only Chrome v69, Firefox Nightly and Opera 56). It’s an experimental feature, is there's another way to do it ?